# glmnet tuning fails in tidymodels with `multi_predict` error despite predicting one output

Tags: r, hyperparameters, glmnet, tidymodels

Using `tidymodels`, I'm trying to predict an outcome as a percentage bound between `0` and `1`. Since it's not a classification, I've been using a logistic regression model with `glmnet` by setting the parameter `family = binomial(link = "logit")`. This works fine when I run through a quick baseline model w/no tuning:

```r
# example spec
example_spec <-
  linear_reg(mode = "regression"
             penalty = 0) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet", 
             family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

But when I try to tune `penalty()` and `mixture()`, I get an error that reads:
`No multi_predict method exists for objects with class _glmnetfit, _modelfit`, even though I just have one predicted variable.

I've used nearly identical code to what is shown in the reprex to tune glmnet hyperparameters for classification problems in the past with no issues (only difference is that I use `logistic_reg` and don't set the `family` parameter when setting the engine). Definitely would appreciate any help or insight on this error!

Here is a reprex of the error:

```r
# libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip

# reprex training set
set.seed(8675309)
reprex_train <- as_tibble(randu)

# add nominal predictors 
reprex_train <- 
  reprex_train %>%
  bind_cols(category = rep(c("category_1", "category_2"), 200))

# rename for clarity
reprex_train <- 
  reprex_train %>%
  rename(outcome = x,
         numeric_1 = y,
         numeric_2 = z)

# preview of training df
reprex_train
#> # A tibble: 400 x 4
#>     outcome numeric_1 numeric_2 category  
#>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>     
#>  1 0.000031  0.000183  0.000824 category_1
#>  2 0.0445    0.156     0.534    category_2
#>  3 0.822     0.873     0.839    category_1
#>  4 0.322     0.649     0.991    category_2
#>  5 0.394     0.827     0.419    category_1
#>  6 0.309     0.927     0.778    category_2
#>  7 0.826     0.309     0.414    category_1
#>  8 0.729     0.742     0.884    category_2
#>  9 0.318     0.393     0.502    category_1
#> 10 0.600     0.846     0.678    category_2
#> # ... with 390 more rows

# bootstrap resampling
set.seed(10101)
reprex_boot <- bootstraps(reprex_train, times = 3)

# recipe
reprex_rec <-
  recipe(outcome ~ ., data = reprex_train) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())

# specification
reprex_spec <-
  linear_reg(mode = "regression",
             penalty = tune(),
             mixture = tune()) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet",
             family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# workflow
reprex_wf <- 
  workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(reprex_rec) %>%
  add_model(reprex_spec) 

# tune
set.seed(12345)
reprex_rs <-
  tune_grid(
    reprex_wf,
    resamples = reprex_boot,
    grid = grid_regular(penalty(), mixture())
  )
#> ! Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/3: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> x Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` met...
#> ! Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/3: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> x Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` met...
#> ! Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/3: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> x Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` met...
#> ! Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/3: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> x Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` met...
#> ! Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/3: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> x Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` met...
#> ! Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/3: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> x Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` met...
#> ! Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/3: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> x Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` met...
#> ! Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/3: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> x Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` met...
#> ! Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/3: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> x Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` met...
#> Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.

reprex_rs
#> Warning: This tuning result has notes. Example notes on model fitting include:
#> preprocessor 1/1, model 1/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` method exists for objects with classes '_glmnetfit', 'model_fit'
#> preprocessor 1/1, model 2/3: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
#> preprocessor 1/1, model 3/3 (predictions): Error: No `multi_predict` method exists for objects with classes '_glmnetfit', 'model_fit'
#> # Tuning results
#> # Bootstrap sampling 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   splits            id         .metrics .notes          
#>   <list>            <chr>      <list>   <list>          
#> 1 <split [400/140]> Bootstrap1 <NULL>   <tibble [6 x 1]>
#> 2 <split [400/146]> Bootstrap2 <NULL>   <tibble [6 x 1]>
#> 3 <split [400/144]> Bootstrap3 <NULL>   <tibble [6 x 1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but you might want to try a beta regression model.

Comment: I have thie same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this way of specifying the model:

```
reprex_spec  <- logistic_reg(
penalty = tune(),
mixture = tune()) %>%
set_engine("glmnet")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, the tidymodel logistic spec can only be used for classification and Im working on a regression problem (it’s predicting % so the response is bound between 0 & 1). I suppose I could use a straightforward linear model with `glmnet` since the majority of the response values are between ~0.2 and 0.8, but ideally I’d like to be able to use a logistic link as best practice

Comment: I suppose *another* way to do so would be to apply the `logit` function to the predicted var prior to analysis, then just tune a straightforward linear model with `glmnet`, and finally transform back to `[0, 1]` with the inverse logit, but I had thought that `glmnet` would have taken care of these steps with the link function